# Is numpy+mkl faster than numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

If numpy+mkl is faster, how much faster is it than numpy?

I found that the numpy+mkl installation package is much larger than numpy, but I can't feel the difference in their speed.

Comment: The MKL version is compiled with support for Intel’s Math Kernel Library. This includes optimized routines for certain operations. You won’t likely observe the gains from this unless you’re really stressing your processor, performing operation that make use of those routines specifically.

Comment: Are you testing the linear algebra routines?

Comment: @TWReever I use Intel's CPU on Windows 10, what computing operations can embody the advantages of mkl?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I often use numpy for matrix operations and data format conversions

Comment: @REA There’s a lot of documentation out there on the MKL, it’s hard to say without knowing exactly what you’re using Numpy for but chances are you’re taking advantage of it to some degree.

Comment: Did we come to some conclusion for this question ?

Answer (score 5):

numpy's standard pip packages are linked to OpenBLAS. Mabey OpenBLAS is in the same ballpark for speed as MKL.
For a detailed comparison of their speeds, please see [Boosting numpy: Why BLAS Matters](http://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html)
and 
[Benchmark OpenBLAS, Intel MKL vs ATLAS](https://github.com/tmolteno/necpp/issues/18)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, maybe just slightly.

I just repeated now benchmark from this site: https://jwalton.info/Python-MKL-openBLAS/.
And the results on current version of `numpy` are similar to those on `intel-numpy`.

Speedup > 1 means MKL is faster.
Speedup < 0 means "standard" numpy (using openBLAS) is faster.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, differences are small. For some functions there is small (~1.1x) speedup. But for most of them there is no speedup and one function is significantly slower in MKL.

Comment: I think many of the functions won't use MKL. Like random